# nodeJS S3.getObject() timing out (is there better options for images?) in Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So I am storing and accessing images in Amazon S3. My code (nodeJS in Lambda) for accessing images is below...

```
//...Other unerelated Code
    var s3Params = {
        "Bucket": "example-bucket",
        "Key": "example-image-key"
    };
    try{
            //some unrelated code getting item from DynamoDB
            image : await s3.getObject(s3Params).promise()


    }catch(err)
    {
        //Handling
    }
```

So this works great... for small images (39.3KB almost instant), but it is timing out for bigger images (3.1MB will timeout after 20 seconds).

Is there a better way to do this? Or should I just expect it to take longer and increase the time out?

Edit: Complete Code Below

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-southeast-2'});
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient;
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
let itemParamters = {
Key: {
    name: event.name,
},
TableName: 'records'
};
var s3Params = {
    "Bucket": "Example-BucketName",
    "Key": "Example key" + event.name + ".jpg"
};
var msg;
var code;


try{
    code = 200;
    msg ={
        item : await db.get(itemParamters).promise(),
        image : await s3.getObject(s3Params).promise()
    };

}catch(err)
{
    code = 500;
    msg = "Error: " + err;
}

var response = {
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" :"*"
    },
    statusCode: code,
    body: msg
};

return response;

};
```

EDIT 2:

After Further Testing the timeout seems to occur during the setting of the response, specifically image.

Comment: Hey @MasterEnzo, I suspect this has something to do with the other code in the lambda, as that is an incredibly long time to get an object of that size from S3. Could you try removing everything else and testing this?

Comment: @razki I have added all my code into the original post, as I am new to this I wouldn't be surprised if it contained the issue. The reason I was looking at the original code posted is because, if I ran the code with "image: await s3.getObject()..." commented out, it ran quickly. If I commented out  "db.get()..." it still would time out. As well as the fact the photo size seemed to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is because you're trying to return the object returned from S3 via JSON which includes the buffer data. The larger the image the more data that will be present. This is why you'll be seeing the timeout.

Example object returned from the call to `.getObject()`

```
{
 AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
 LastModified: 2020-04-05T13:52:07.000Z,
 ContentLength: 78392,
 ETag: '"d009e410*****"',
 ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
 Metadata: {},
 Body: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 ... 124764 more bytes>
}
```

If you were trying to obtain the hash only from the image to make a comparison you could do something like:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const s3 = new AWS.S3()

exports.handler = async () => {
    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: 'bucket',
        Key: 'test.jpg',
    }

    const { ETag } = await s3.getObject(s3Params).promise()

    return {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        statusCode: 200,
        hash: ETag,
    }
}
```

However I suspect you actually want to return the image to the user, I'd suggest looking at the following resource:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

Comment: thank you for your help, I've got it working, for a 3.1MB image it completes the function in about 4 seconds. Would this be about right or is something still wrong?

Comment: No issues. Totally depends on what the desired outcome is...? the code I posted above will return the MD5 hash (ETag in S3 land). Which is why you'll be seeing that lambda function return in the 4 seconds.